# Dragons and serpents in Norse and Indo-European mythology

Tags: norse, dragons

Apart from christianity, serpents and dragons are affirmative symbolic beings, i.e. serpents symbolize renewal, healing and rebirth (skin-sloughing of serpents, Ouroboros).

In Norse mythology, that is a mythology of Indo-European descent, what do dragons symbolize for i.e. the Vikings.

Dragons and dragon ornamentation appear i.e. on ships, stave churches, ...

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mythology and Folklore SE! Any specific dragon in mind?

Comment: No not really, i know the Norse dragons and their mythology (of which i wonder how much it is tainted by later christian worldview). What is the name of the dragons on the stave churches and the dragons on the ships ?

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit challenging to delimit the quest of this question. 
For instant, there are lists (thulas) of serpents, which may, and may not be considered dragons. The mythological Jörmundgandr ("the world serpent"), for instant, I find Jörmungandr reflected in the most classic dragon of all Norse, Fafnir, because of the name, quite simply signifying 'Fathom'. He's much known as he also is found in the German Niebelungenlied, that Richard Wagner his Ring-cycle upon. It seems that Dragons are originally human. Well, I'm not interpreting either Æsir, Vanir, Dwarves, Youthunns, or Elves of the dark and of the light, as not human (double negation there). Fafnir's fate is profoundly reflected not merely in Wagner's work, but also in the works of Tolkien, particularly regarding the ring, Andvaranaut. It is this ring's curse, or Fafnir's obsession with the external alchemy related to the Ring of Andvari, that turns him into the dragon. In this context the Dragon is quite clearly a transformation due to perversion and obsession.

If the Norse serpents are part of the deliberation here, even Oðinn is a dragon of sorts, as he turns into Bólwork, in order to get hold of the entheogenic compound brew, relating to the greeting (skål!), aka the peace between the Vanir and Æsir, according to Snorre Sturlasson, the main contenders of the Trojan war, fascilitated by King Lear aka Youthunn Ægir. It seems to me that the ornamental dragon-serpents of ships and churches are more related to this mytheme, than that of Fafnir. This mytheme is reflected in the Kerukeion aka Caduceus, the biblical Nehushtan of Moses, and the old Sumerian Ningishida..

The ultimate viking hero, with a name that could be translated as Arrow's-Edge, is famed for having battled with the sea-monster Kraken, often likened to Chthulu, or Hafgufa, the mother of all sea-monsters.

The Norse heraldic and ornamental dragons are called Lindworms, interpreted as the Norse name for dragons. Fafnir is called a Lindworm in the Saga-litterature.

Six Lindworms are mentioned as the offspring of Gráfvitnir (Grave-witness, Grave-visitor, or grave-wolf): 
Góinn, Móinn, Grábakr, Gráfvölluðr, Ófnir and Sváfnir. 
My suggestion to their meaning is: 
The (subtle) intestinal life-force of (sacrificial) animals - Gó(r)inn.
The (subtle) interior of arable land - Mó(r)inn.
The foul force in shit or leftovers - Grábakr.
The rolling force coming from burial mounds - Gráfvölluðr.
The force of descendance - Ófnir.
The force of ascendance - Sváfnir.
This is quite tentative, based on my own fragmentary research and dubious competence in Norse language and cult.

I hope this was a bit to work on.

Comment: What i think is strange is that Jörmungandr, is said to encircle Midgard ouroboros-like and in addition that Jörmungandr is poisonuous. In a more accurate interpretation of Norse (and also Indo-European) mythology, in that dragons or serpents are affirmative beings, Jörmungandr encircles Yggdrasil, the entire cosmos. The meaning of this is that the Indo-Europeans thought the universe to be eternal and always renewing. As i think that dragons and serpents are affirmative symbols it is strange to link them to poison and death like it is done in the christianized version of Norse mythology

Comment: First of all, if for once we would take the words and works of Snorri Sturlasson and his bardic lineage as an expression of integrity, rather than symptoms of vicarious intentions, we will find a pride referencing the intercultural dimensionality of the Norse sagas, wisdom, perception and cult-practices. The Norse calendar, for instant, draws upon a finno-ugric traditon. Snorre is referencing the Aenead, explaining that Aeneas is identical to Oðinn' and Greeth's son Viðareu. The metempsychotic element is superimportant I think. Ethnic identification is primarily by manners, bloodlines less.

Comment: When we speak of christianisation, this is most often terribly misleading. I wonder if anyone can document any totalitarian, violent spread of christianity prior to Carolian feudalism. I believe there is proof of it, but haven't found it. Yet, in the earlier, pre-chalchedonian stratas of christianity, the prevailing mood of spreading the Word, is by blending in, and treating the gospel as the grand syncretic integer, bringing all the lost tribes back home to the hope of the Promised Land.

Comment: At least the pre-Nicean christians regard themselves as true Jews, although distinquishing themselves ideologigially from Jews anchoring their Jewishness in Blood & Soil. Is not Kvasir eponymous to Khazaria? The huge Khaganate that made Judaism it's religion, buffering between the Byzantine Christendom and Golden Age Baghdad Khalifate. Snorre is surely aware of the expansion of Gardarike (King Sveinald /Prince Sviatoslav I) on the expanse of the Khazarians. The Norse is a compound, with the first strata of humans being Youthunns, thereupon Finns and Quéns, if we read the Orkneyar Sagas.

Comment: The premise is to regard the supernatural beings, Vanir, Æsir, Youthunns, Elves as humans, or avatars of different populations, as suggested in particular by the scaldic tradition of the Icelanders in exile from the feudalism of the royal House Ynglings in alliance with the House of Wessex who unified England, as well as the House of Liudolfingers! The Elves and the Goðs, are explained by the story of the grandson's of Nór, the eponymous anchestor of Norway, and Norse, through his son Raumœ. Two of his sons, Finn & Brand become Finn-elf & Goð-brand, following the Joþunn-Goþ-Elf alliance.

Comment: The third son of Raumœ, Bjørn (Bear) stays with the Motherline, becoming Joþunn-bear upon initiation. This whole saga begins in the upper north, with the very instituting of the midwinter-bloþ, by Þorrœ of Youthland. He got three kids: Gói the big sister, extremely beautiful, yet merely an adolescent, disappears during the heydays of the bloþ in Gandrwich. This prompts the brothers to search for her, but they're simply not yet old enough, until three winters, I believe. Nór travels by land, whose ways are called the Nórway, his brother travels by sea. Strangely I've never heard of Górway.

Comment: It's a fascinating story with a surprising end. It, in danger of spoiling, results with a junction of the House of Þorre with the House of Svaðe. This House is a branch of the Scyldings centred upon Lejre in Zealand, related to both Wagner's Ring-cycle and Shakespeare's Hamlet. The Norse milieu spans from the Black Sea to the Varangian north, encompassing the Langobardians, Burgundians and Rugians, Swedes, Danes and Geats. Not merely in its geography, of course, but as compound of identities. Snorri identifies Prince Tros, with Þorr, the one with the hammer, as son of King Memnon of Ethiopia.

Comment: What prompted me to this exegesis was the notion of a dichotomic mindset in stead of perceiving (magnetic-like) fields of bipolarity. The pride of the Norse scaldic tradition was to encompass both the Asian East and the European, even seeing themselves as fascilitating the peace between the Greek Danoi and the Hetittic Trojans, although that may have spurred some arrogance and aristocracy as well. Anyhow, there are no purity of races. It is evident that the saga resources that didn't build the modern national identity of the Scandinavians in the 19th Century, is far less known, even today.

Comment: In spite of common notions, the Samis are as Norse, more so if we relate to to Nór's saga than are the common blend of Norwegians (I'm Norwegian). The challenge is that the Sami's are identified with Þrolls and Þrælls, Youþunns and Hrisir. Closer reading of the Sagas themselves reveal that they are tremendously more complex and very much human, than both folk and common perception tells, yet also the translations into modern Scandinavian are sometimes a study in derogatory perceptions. 

Back to the Judeo-christian notion of the snakes, or lindworm.... Let me finally conclude..

Comment: Christians identifying evil with the snake commits a terrible exegetic mistake. 
Yet the Snake became a methonym - a pars et toto-symbol - of idolatry. God told Moses to erect an Ashera Pole with a brazen snake (or two along, like the staff of Hermes).

Comment: It , the artwork, is called Necchas Necchesatan in the second Book of Kings, I think. The Holy Person of the Spirt told Moses to do it in order so that Israelites who saw the impressive figure, also adorning the Holy Arc would be protected from dying from the bites of the "fiery serpents", which inevitably was released as consequence of their antagonisms against Moses, and abuse of the Holy name of the Personalities. Yet during the wicked rule of King Ahaz this became perversly fetishized, thus his son, a true Melkitzadik, a just king, dismantles it in concord with the allbirther.

Comment: The name of the world-serpent, Jórmundgandr is amazingly fascinating in this context. Recall the name of the World tree, among several in the Norse texts, is Yggdrasill, which is understood as Ygg's Stud. Ygg is explained, in the Grimnesmeal, I think, as Oðinn's name in the age before he became Oðinn. The Drasill may not be simply identical to Oðinns 8 footed horse, Sleipnieu, although yes, but rather the image of a whole lot becoming one, a Drove of Horses. I believe Yggdrasill is no less than the whole Drove of Ygg.

Comment: Ygg, I see as an auger, a drill, closely related to the name of Oðinn in the shape of a snake, Bólwork (Snakepitworker and Bottleworker). I could go on.. 
Well, let me sum it up with this last piece of information. The Jórmundgandr serpent is amazing. Jór is horse, although something about it, of course. Mund, is Time, more in terms of appointed time than chronological time, yet all time is Mund. A word encompassing both World and Time,(cf. mundus) similar to the Hebrew Olam. Gand, is the magick hrod (cf. Gandalf), but as with the snake-wand of Moses, the word signifies the wiz of spells.